# How do I save a form in double nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model, controller, nested-forms

I have three models: `Event`, `Workout`, and `Round`.

A person can create a event, that includes a workout, and configure number of sets and weights through round.

I am currently using `cocoon` gem to create a nested form. I am able to use the form and save Event and Workout, however, Round is not being saved.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workouts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :rounds, :through => :workouts
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workouts, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :rounds, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rounds, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Round < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :workout
  belongs_to :event
end
```

I currently have my routes set like this.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'static_pages#index'
  resources :events do
    resources :workouts do
        resources :rounds
      end
  end
```

In my controller, this is how I have my new methods.

```
  New Method for Event
  def new
    @event = current_user.events.new
  end

  New Method for Workout
  def new
    @workout = Workout.new
  end

  New Method for Round
  def new
    @round = Round.new
  end
```

I currently have the form under Events' view folder. Under `show.html.erb` of Events view file, I am trying to display Rounds as well by

```
<% @workout.rounds.each do |round| %>
  <%= round.weight %>
<% end %>
```

But I am getting `undefined method for rounds`. Is it not possible to display round in Event view?

Thanks for the help!

---

**Edit 1**:

Here is my nested forms. 
At the top, I have form for Event.

```
<%= simple_form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>

      <h3>Work Outs</h3>
      <div id="workouts">
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :workouts do |workout| %>
          <%= render 'workout_fields', f: workout %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="links">
          <%= link_to_add_association 'add workout', f, :workouts %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :start_time %><br>
        <%= f.datetime_select :start_time %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :end_time %><br>
        <%= f.datetime_select :end_time %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :description %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
      </div>
        <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Create new Workout" %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

</form>
```

Then there is a form for Workout

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <%= f.input :name %>

  <div class="rounds">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :rounds, :wrapper => 'inline' do |round| %>
      <%= render 'round_fields', f: round %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association 'add round', f, :rounds, :render_option => { :wrapper => 'inline' } %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove workout", f %>
</div>
```

And finally, I have the form for Round

```
<div class="nested-fields">

    <table class="table round-table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <% index = 0 %>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :rounds do |round| %>
            <%= render 'set_fields', {f: round, index: index} %>
            <% index = index + 1 %>
        <% end %>
      </td>
      <td>Previous Weight</td>
      <td><%= f.input_field :weight %></td>
      <td><%= f.input_field :repetition %></td>
      <td><%= link_to_remove_association "remove rounds", f %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I am able to create round on rails console and save them. But when I use the form on the web, I cannot save them.

---

**EDIT 2**

This is currently how I have the `event_params` and `workout_params` set-up.

```
def event_params
  params.fetch(:event, {}).permit(:title, :description, :start_time, :end_time, :workouts_attributes => [:id, :name, :category, :_destroy])
end
```

Then the `workout_params`:

```
def workout_params
  params.require(:workout).permit(:name, :category, :rounds_attributes => [:id, :weight, :set, :repetition, :_destroy])
end
```

I am confused why the form would save Event and Workout. But Round always returns an empty array.

Comment: Are you setting @workout in your `EventsController#show` action?

Comment: I thought that wasn't necessary due to has_many associations.Should I set workout to event.workouts ?

Answer (score 2):

Finally solved it!

I had to have an association in the `params` as well. Double nested association.

```
def event_params
  params.fetch(:event, {}).permit(:title, :description, :start_time, :end_time, :workouts_attributes => [:id, :name, :category, :_destroy])
end
```

For my `event_params`, I only had `:workouts_attributes`. I thought having `:rounds_attributes` in `workout_params` would be okay. But I needed to have `rounds_attributes` in `event_params` as well.

Fixing it like below fixed the issue.

```
def event_params
  params.fetch(:event, {}).permit(:title, :description, :start_time, :end_time, :workouts_attributes => [:id, :name, :category, :_destroy, :rounds_attributes => [:id, :weight, :set, :repetition, :_destroy]])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you already have `rounds` attribute in Events model (`has_many :rounds, :through => :workouts`), why not use it?

```
<% @event.rounds.each do |round|
  <%= round.weight %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I did not realize I could directly access round from @event. thank you.

But it seems like none of my rounds are being saved, because no numbers are being displayed from rounds..